# Email hosting for corporate as well as Bulk sending needs

Tags: linux, email, exchange, email-server, zimbra

I have to send around 1000 emails daily to my clients. These emails are basically the Price alerts of the Exchange they have subscribed to and are very critical for them to receive on time.

I already have a Windows VPS server as well as a Dedicated cPanel linux server with me.

Now my server provider says that I have to purchase a bulk email from them or any other provider otherwise the sending so many mails from our domain may result in blacklisting by many other providers.

I am not sure what to do.

Can't I install something? or use cPanel's email to send mail? Can't I ensure delivery by Purchasing an SSL?? I am very very new in this field and I don't know what to do. I want to do it myself and on my servers.

Please help.

Comment: If you need immediate delivery, email is not the technology for this project. There ate many ways emails can get delayed form unites of hours, and that is an expected part of the smtp protocol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bulk email sending is a specialist’s role these days, that's why you're getting the advice you are.

The big mail vendors like Mandril and Sendgrid maintain *farms* of machines not because of scale, but because of IP reputation. One of the most effective spam fighting techniques available to us is a database that tracks how well behaved IP addresses are with respect to sending spam. The big mail vendors pay very close attention to what happens when they *deliver* mail since that is the only feedback they'll get that an IP address they own is drifting into blacklist territory.

What happens after an IP of theirs get blacklisted varies by vendor, but feedback to the actual customer happens. Also, as IP address reputation is not something these bulk mail vendors can *directly* control, they have to put the now-bad address aside somewhere until they can rebuilt its positive reputation; which means they need a new IP to replace the slandered one.

No, there isn't a cpanel widget or software package you can install to ensure both accurate and non-spam-folder delivery of email that users have actually asked for. In fact, it simply can't be done by a small infrastructure anymore.

Email is a poor choice for time-sensitive delivery of information, which is why so many apps have moved to push notifications.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. We will go with some kind of enterprise solution. I came across SMTP Relay Services while googling. Will that be OK?

Comment: @KumarRavi It can be, though the best bet would be a dedicated bulk mail seller. They often have an API interface so you can work with them more programatically than a simple mail relay.